Question about the proof of Euclidean algorithm.
Theorem
If $a = bq+r, \text{then gcd}(a,b)=\text{gcd}(b,r) ... \text{gcd}(r_{i-1},r_i) = \text{gcd}(r_i,0)=r_i$.
Proof:
Let $d$ be a common divisor of $a$ and $b: d|a, d|b \implies d|(a-bq)\implies d|r$.
Let $e$ be a common divisor of $b$ and $r: e|b, e|r \implies e|bq+r \implies e|a$
Then d is a common divisor of $a$ and $b \iff d$ is a common divisor of $b$ and $r$.
From the first line I get that if $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ then it is a divisor of $b$ and $r$. But what does the second line accomplish in this case?

The second line proves the converse. If $e$ (or call it again $d$)  divides $b$ and $r$, then $e$ also divides $a$ and $b$.

@DietrichBurde Thank you!

first line is: "$d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b\implies d$ is a common divisor of $r$.  The second line is "$d$ is a common divisor of $b$ and $r\implies d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$.  Thus the third line.... and thus as $a,b$ and $b,r$ have the same set of common divisors, $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$.  Applying induction we get the chain $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)=\gcd(r,r_2)=....=\gcd(r_{i-1},r_i)$.  And knowing that the $r_i$ are decreasing natural numbers, the chain must eventually end. It ends with $r_{i-1}=kr_i +0$ and so $\gcd(r_{i-1},r_i)=\gcd(r_i,0)=r_i$.

@fleablood Why a comment and not an official answer?

@PaulFrost The question was only about the second line, and the explanation is too short for an answer (see the comment). Basically the line ends with $e\mid a$, and the OP only needed to be remembered that $e\mid b$ was also assumed.
